# How to Inject Lists From Spring Properties Files based on locale

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, properties, attached-properties

I use spring boot to load list of object From Spring Properties File as explained [here](https://mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-configurationproperties-example/) and it works fine. but l have multi Properties for localization. so the question is how to load the list From Properties File based on local?

*note:  I use `ResourceBundleMessageSource` for localization but it read one message at a time it didn't read a list and didn't convert it to object.